# What escapes are excluded when Perl regex interpolation is off?

Tags: regex, perl, string-interpolation

I'm curious as to what escape sequences get excluded from being matched in a Perl regular expression when interpolation is turned off, say by using an apostrophe (single-quote) as a delimiter for `m''`, and also why. The description of interpolation in [perlop](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators) mentions that:

> No interpolation is performed at this stage. Any backslashed sequences including `\\` are treated at the stage to parsing regular expressions.

However, a testing of the escape sequence found in [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), shows that not all escape sequences are treated the same.

So, I've tested all the simple escapes listed in the "Escape Sequences" section of the [perlre](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlre.html#Regular-Expressions), and found that some are "off" while some are "on". There appears to be a correspondence between the "on" and "off" escapes and the "character escapes" and "escape modifiers" descriptions in [perlrebackslash](http://perldoc.perl.org/perlrebackslash.html#Regular-Expressions), respectively. I haven't tested all the possible escapes listed on that page, just the ones from those two groups, thus far.

Even if I test all the possible escapes, I'm not sure I understand why some still work when interpolation is off, while others do not. Can anyone enlighten me?

---

**update:** As @tchrist suggested, here are some examples. I essentially used variations on the following shell code to test these against some user input from STDIN:

```
perl -e "use 5.012; while(<>) { say 'YES' if m'\t';}"
```

The escapes `\e`, `\f`, `\n`, `\r`, and `\t`, when used in a non-interpolated matching construct, such as `m'\t'` (etc.) will still match the special characters they escape instead of their literal string representations. This is the same matching behavior I see when I use an interpolated form of matching (e.g. `m/\t/`), which is what I meant by still "working".

On the other hand, modifiers like `\L`, `\U`, `\l`, and `\u` do not function the same inside of `m''` as inside of `m//`. For example `m'\uthis'` does not match the input: "This is a string," while `m/\uthis/` does match such an input. The first form *will* match the input: "\uthis is a string."

Comment: ..."discluded"? [You keep using that word. I do not think it means what you think it means.](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disclude)

Comment: Fair enough, I should have written "excluded". But a quick Googling shows that common usage of "disclude" is the same as "exclude".

Comment: [No.](http://answers.yahoo.com/question/index?qid=20080209154345AAxk9mI) [No](http://dictionary.reference.com/browse/disclude) [it](http://en.wiktionary.org/wiki/disclude) [isn't](http://www.allwords.com/word-disclude.html).

Comment: Give examples of which ones you think “work”, and which you think do not.

Comment: @cljacobs you should answer this yourself and accept your answer. I'd like to add that the \' escape also works

Answer (score 1):

Its the difference between single quoted string and double quoted string, those rules are seperate from regex patterns

so `m'$foo'` is like `'$foo'` and not like `"$foo"`

```
use Data::Dump;
$foo = 12;
dd qr/$foo/i;
dd qr'$foo'i;
__END__
qr/12/i
qr/$foo/i
```

so if using interpolation, you're matching 12
and if you've disabled interpolation, you're matching `$`, the end of line (or string) followed by foo

More on this in http://perldoc.perl.org/perlop.html#Quote-and-Quote-like-Operators

**update:** on a side note, in addition to Data::Dump, both Data::Dumper and Data::Dump::Streamer "dump" `qr'$foo'i` erroneously as `qr/$foo/i`